# Is every graph isomorphic (as a variety) to a hyperplane via the projection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $f : \mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}$ be any function (not necessarily regular) such that the set $\{(p,f(p))~|~p \in \mathbb{A}^n \}$ is an algebraic variety in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. Then projection onto the first $n$ coordinates induces a bijective morphism of algebraic varieties. Need this always be an isomorphism?

Clearly, this is equivalent to showing that $f$ must, in fact, always be regular whenever its graph $G$ is algebraic. Here's what I've been able to deduce when the base field $k$ is algebraically closed and of characteristic $0$: Since $G$ surjects onto a variety of dimension $n$ and is properly contained in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, it itself must be of dimension $n$, and so is the zero set of a single polynomial $F \in k[x_1, ..., x_{n+1}]$. The function $f$ then assigns a point $p \in \mathbb{A}^n$ to the necessarily unique zero of $F(p)$, viewed as a polynomial in $x_{n+1}$. If we Noether normalize, then we may assume $F$ is monic in $x_{n+1}$. So, write $F(p) = (x_{n+1} - f(p))^m$. Since the coefficient of the $(m-1)^{\text{th}}$ power of $x_{n+1}$ in $F$ is a polynomial equal to $-m \cdot f(p)$ for all $p$, and we are in characteristic $0$, we divide to obtain $f$ is a polynomial function as desired.

I'm thinking there ought to be a more elegant proof of this even when $k$ is not algebraically closed or of nonzero characteristic, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is a very strange way to attempt to solve this problem. What happens if you try to construct two maps in the category of varieties which compose both ways to the identity? Will projection onto $X$ and $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ work?

Comment: @KReiser That latter map won't be a morphism of varieties unless $f$ is first demonstrated to be regular.

Comment: Okay, great, there's your answer. $f$ regular implies that the graph is isomorphic to $X$. This is in fact an if and only statement (full proof, see EGA I, Corollary 5.3.11).

Comment: Thanks for the reference; the converse is exactly what I was asking for. However, in EGA I, I can't find a Corollary 5.3.11 having to do with this. See: https://i.imgur.com/cDzdnNO.png

Comment: Should be page 133 in the NUMDAM version.